# Обновить дату в базе (mysql) через php

Tags: php, mysql

Не понимаю в чем проблема, но дата никак не записывается в базу.
Тип поля datetime.

```
<?php
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","p98521z1_q");
 if (!$db)
{ echo " Ошибка: Невозможно подключиться к MySQL серверу. Пожалуйста, попробуйте позже."; exit; }
mysqli_select_db($db, "p98521z1_q") or die("Нет такой таблицы!");

$s="UPDATE users SET user_come='$date'";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$s);
if($result){echo "запись добавлена";}
else{echo 'no';}
  mysqli_close($db);
 ?>
```

Comment: Вот там где вы делаете `echo 'no';` выводите не `no`, а ошибку возвращаемую `mysqli_error()`.

Comment: Все, спасибо, проблема найдена!

Comment: @KsB, а рассказать сообществу, в чем же была проблема?